# Why do my text fields and text areas not align when they have the same width?

Tags: css, textarea, alignment, textfield

Here's the simplest example:

```
<textarea id="text_area" name="text_area" style="width:280px">
</textarea>
<input id="text_field" name="text_field" style="width:280px" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the padding and margin values to 0px.

Comment: no dice.  That didn't change anything, and I verified the margin/padding with firebug.

Comment: It is the same in all browsers? Since i know that Safari is annoying when it comes to things like this.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the border property as well.  Adding the following to both elements fixed the problem:

```
border:1px solid #ccc;
```

Comment: I thought you had the border set to 1px solid #000 because the border on the above form looks like that.

Comment: I hadn't set the border properties, so not sure what they were defaulting to.  Edit your answer and I'll accept.